# Why do I have 10 partitions ? Which one should I choose to give Linux more memory?

Tags: partitioning, ram

I am new to Ubuntu and I fell in love, but I want to have more memory. This is a answered question, but I do not know which one can I touch from windows and give it to Ubuntu.

Furthermore, I don't know why do I have 10 partitions if I didn't do anything about it

I have windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

I a noob so I do not know for example what swap is or what ntfs stands for. These are the partitions shown by gparted

[image: partitions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest partition (sda4) is the windows partition. You can move some of it over to your Ubuntu partition (ext4). The swap partition is used by Ubuntu when your RAM is full. ntfs is the Microsoft file system, so everything with ntfs is windows-related. I'm not sure why you have so many ntfs partitions and what they're for. The efi system partition is OS independent and it's for booting your OS.

On my laptop I have a EFI system partition, Microsoft reserved partition, windows partition, Ubuntu partition, swap partition, and a windows recovery partition.

Comment: Windows 10, by default, create four partitions. The fifth is factory recover partition, typical to Windows 10 OEM computers.

Comment: I think I have 2 hard disk, one is for recovery, the other one  is for windows... it should be the reason that I have more partitions ? Make sense ?